# Crash when accessing NSMutableDictionary by string, in 2 different ways?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutabledictionary

I have the following method:

```
-(QFFriend*)getFriendById:(NSString*)fid
{
    TFLog(@"NList %@", self.nFlist);
    TFLog(@":%@:%@:", @"3", fid);
    TFLog(@"%@", [self.nFlist valueForKey:@"3"]);
//    TFLog(@"%@", [self.nFlist valueForKey:fid]);
}
```

And when I run it WITH the comment, I get this result: (and crash because I left out the return)

```
2013-04-12 07:39:49:972 QF[42881:2311] NList {
    2 = "<QFFriend: 0x1dd61970>";
    3 = "<QFFriend: 0x1dd76570>";
    4 = "<QFFriend: 0x1dd84a70>";
    7 = "<QFFriend: 0x1dd70760>";
}
2013-04-12 07:39:49:974 QF[42881:2311] :3:3:
2013-04-12 07:39:49:976 QF[42881:2311] <QFFriend: 0x1dd76570>
```

However, If I uncomment that line I get another crash, can someone explain what could be wrong?

```
2013-04-12 07:43:28:736 QuizFuzz[42912:2311] NList {
    2 = "<QFFriend: 0x1c5888c0>";
    3 = "<QFFriend: 0x1c5a5c30>";
    4 = "<QFFriend: 0x1c5acaf0>";
    7 = "<QFFriend: 0x1c5badf0>";
}
2013-04-12 07:43:28:738 QF[42912:2311] :3:3:
2013-04-12 07:43:28:740 QF[42912:2311] <QFFriend: 0x1c5a5c30>
2013-04-12 07:43:28.741 QF[42912:907] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d8521b0
2013-04-12 07:43:28:754 QF[42912:2311] ERROR: -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d8521b0
2013-04-12 07:43:28.756 QF[42912:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d8521b0'
```

How can the two last calls not be equivalent? I send in a string in both cases!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error is:

> -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

which means `fid` is a `NSNumber` not `NSString`

also, you should use `objectForKey:` rather `valueForKey:` to get object from dictionary

so try this

```
[self.nFlist valueForKey:[fid stringValue]]
```

Comment: +1, but just out of curiosity, why use `description` instead of `stringValue`?

Comment: Thanks. This is just hilarious that I couldnt figure that out. I was like "I never used nsnumber!", but ye, I did.

Comment: @lnafziger because while writing the answer i forget there is `stringValue`... thanks for point out

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are getting two different crashes when using what would seem to be very similar code. But if you want to fix the crashes, I believe the call you are looking for is:

```
[self.nFlist objectForKey:@"3"];
```

[NSDictionary Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectForKey%3a)

/* update */
Actually, after reading your crash logs more and looking at the TFLogs. I would take a guess that the fid object that is getting passed in is an NSNumber, not an NSString like you expect. To confirm this, you could log out: `TFLog(@"fid.class: %@", fid.class);` This logs the class, not the description, so you can see what you have. `NSNumber` with the value 3 and `NSString` with the value @"3" would both log out as 3.